# flair import failing on mac ubuntu and google colab

Tags: opennlp, allennlp, flair

i am trying to use flair nlp framework ,

https://github.com/flairNLP/flair

but getting error

```py
# load the NER tagger
tagger = SequenceTagger.load('ner')
```

tried on local , remote and other machine . all failing as its not able to download a model from s3 .google colab also gives same error .

all give error message as:

```
OSError: HEAD request failed for url https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/alan-nlp/resources/models-v0.4/NER-conll03-english/en-ner-conll03-v0.4.pt with status code 301.
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue, I don't know what happen with the link but I found another one.

You can look flair master repo https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/flair/models/sequence_tagger_model.py
on the  def _fetch_model(model_name)  line 971.
There are using another path already "https://nlp.informatik.hu-berlin.de/resources/models", so they change to that path instead of alan-nlp.

So you can find your model here https://nlp.informatik.hu-berlin.de/resources/models/ner/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this.

Note that [flair now hosts](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair) the majority of their models on [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/models?library=flair&sort=downloads).

Most likely what you need to do is install the latest version of flair which has the `sequence_tagger_model.py` (and probably others) pointing to the right link.

I had to uninstall flair, and then reinstall it:

```
pip uninstall flair
pip install flair
```

to ensure it worked.

Comment: This did not work for me. I am still getting the same error even though I am using flair version 0.11.